# Accessing global state from a slice

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

I'm using @reduxjs/toolkit createSlice feature for the whole application.
I often have a need to access other slices's state. One common example is for the "one to many relationship" where children are stored in normalized form by "byParentId" key in their respective state. So, when user makes some "parent" active, almost every selector / reducer / saga effect in the "child" needs access to "parent" state "active" field. Initially, I simply added "activeParent" field to the action while combining reducers. Later on, with more such cases I ended up with just "global" variable in action with the whole state for every action instead of crafting data preparation in the combine reducers function.

This also improved performance in redux-saga, where `yield select(selector)` calls where replaced with synchronous `selector(global)`

[Here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/601) @gaeron claims this approach to be an anti-pattern, which can be usually solved by:

> Removing that logic from reducer and moving it to a selector

Good, when possible.

> Passing additional information into the action;

Sometimes it is good, but often introduces unnecessary performance hit.
To pass additional information to an action it should be retrieved by useSelector into component which may otherwise don't need it, read: more redraws.

> Letting the view code perform two actions.

Again, good, but not always. It requires to put sequences of actions in multiple components instead of having a simple logic,
when one action results in another one.

One mentioned problem:

> reducers become coupled to each other’s state shape which complicates any refactoring or change in the state structure.

can be easily avoided by using selectors instead of accessing "foreign" state directly.

Is there a real reason for this approach to be anti-pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the *entire* root state into an action is definitely an anti-pattern and should be avoided.

You *may* want to *sometimes* [put additional data from the state into specific actions if the reducer logic needs it](https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers#how-do-i-share-state-between-two-reducers-do-i-have-to-use-combinereducers).

Beyond that, I'd need to see more specific details on what you're trying to do and what the code looks like to offer additional advice.

Comment: thanks to your reply I found this thread https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/601 where @gaeron mentioned that it is an anti-pattern but a lot of people actually disagree. Unfortunately, my question remains open: why this pattern claimed to be "anti"?